# ¿Cuándo perdió el infinitivo el estatus de "modo"?

Tags: gramática, verbos, historia, rae, infinitivo

En la *Primera gramática de la lengua castellana*, se recoge lo siguiente:

> LOS MODOS de significar los verbos son quatro.
>      *Indicativo*, [...].
>      *Subjuntivo*, [...].
>      *Imperativo*, [...].
>      *Infinitivo*, el que no se ciñe á tiempos, números, ni personas, y necesita otro verbo que determine el sentido, como: conviene *callar*: quiero *escribir*. Por esto no debiera contarse el infinitivo entre los modos, pues esta palabra *amar* por si sola no dice quien ama, quando, ni como; pero sin embargo llaman comunmente los gramáticos *modo* á esta palabra principal, y raiz de cada verbo.

Es decir, que ya en la primera gramática se contaba que el *infinitivo* no debería ser un modo, pero aun así lo incluyeron como tal por influencia de los gramáticos más eminentes de la época. No sé si será porque lo que se entendía entonces como *modo* pueda diferir ligeramente de lo que hoy se entiende como tal. El caso es que hoy se considera que hay tres modos, habiendo perdido definitivamente el *infinitivo* tal estatus. Pero, ¿cuándo tuvo lugar definitivamente esta pérdida de estatus del infinitivo como *modo* en la gramática de la RAE?